# Python : Why I need to reopen a file to succeed in these two manipulations

Tags: python

This should be basic but I can't find a quick response to my question, sorry if this is a double.

I am writing a small code to learn how to manipulate files and count the number of lines, words and of character inside a txt file.
Could you please explain why in the code below if I don't reload for the second time the file using another `with open()`, the code fails to count the `len(f.read)` properly? Without it, it returns 0.
Comments to improve the code are welcomed.

```
def wc(nomFichier):
    nb_car=0
    nb_words=0
    nb_lig=0
    with open(nomFichier) as f:
        for line in f:
            words = line.split()
            nb_words += len(words)
            nb_lig +=1 
    with open(nomFichier) as f:  #Why I need to reload the file?
        nb_car=len(f.read()) #f.read().stripignore to ignore ligne\n 
    f.close()    
    return (nb_car, nb_words, nb_lig)
```

Comment: `f.seek(0)` should be enough.

Comment: @bereal provided code to get the file position back to the beginning before starting to read.

Comment: Thanks @bereal .  Where should I use seek? in all cases I want to follow the methods given by a first course in python and seek does not figure there.

Comment: Your options are `seek`, re-open, or read the file to a variable/list and read that how many times you need...

Comment: @AymaneFihadi the question linked as a duplicate has the explanation. Call it every time you need to start reading the file over. You can check the [file object documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to reopen the file.

```py
def word_count(file_path):
    count_chars=0
    count_words=0
    count_lines=0
    with open(file_path) as f:
        for line in f:
            count_chars += len(line)
            count_words += len(line.split())
            count_lines +=1  
    return (count_chars, count_words, count_lines)
```

Note that I changed the variable names to one I think are more appropriate.